# C# Reporting via query

Tags: c#, sql, reporting

hi everyone i have this code here

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.StoreDBConnection);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String test = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        var dept = Properties.Settings.Default.GiftDepartment;
        MessageBox.Show(""+test+"");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DeptNo,DeptSales,DeptCustomers FROM StoreSalesDetail where DeptNo="+dept+" and ProcDate>="+test+"", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
        da.Fill(ds);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables[1]));
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

    }
```

Sample data in my table

```
2013-05-03 00:00:00.000,2,120.0000,1,1
2013-05-04 00:00:00.000,2,50.0000,1,1
```

test returns the date 2013-05-04 so why does my report return both date in the >= query?

Comment: Put a while loop after your Fill operation and enumerate all the rows in your first data table. Do you see both rows (trying to determine whether this is a query/data issue or a reporting tool issue.

Comment: Can you give me a example of the while loop you want me to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using datediff for more precision. Do wrap input value [test] in single quotes.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DeptNo,DeptSales,DeptCustomers FROM StoreSalesDetail where DeptNo="+dept+" and datediff(d, '" + test + "', ProcDate) >=0", con);
```

Comment: i actually just figured out out my promblem i need to do this SELECT DeptNo,DeptSales,DeptCustomers FROM StoreSalesDetail where DeptNo="+dept+" and ProcDate>='"+test+"'", con);